# Is it possible to set HTML5 Audio player's size using % in CSS?

Tags: html, css, audio, html5-audio

Is it possible to style the `width` of the HTML5 `audioplayer` in `%`?
I tried it, but I found no solution.

Comment: Could You please expand on what have You tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't - at least not reliably across browsers and OSs. Every browser (or mobile OS) has its own design for the HTML5 audio player / `audio` tag, and most of them won't react to any attempts to change it via CSS at all.

One way to work around that is to use the jQuery plugin "jPlayer" (http://jplayer.org/) which uses HTML5 audio wherever possible, has a Flash fallback option, and has its own default "skin". But it also allows you to build your own skin for it. That requires really getting into its structure (i.e. learning by trying), but once you've understood it, it gives you quite some freedom to create your own audio player design.

If I understood it correctly, they hide the default interface of the HTML5 audio player and set up a HTML/JS structure which accesses the available JS events controling audio playback. Those html elements have classes which then can be styled by yourself via CSS rules.

Answer (score 2):

In 2016 most browsers support simply applying CSS width %:

```css
audio {
  width: 80%
}
```

```html
<audio controls id="player" src="https://ia801009.us.archive.org/4/items/BeatlesGreatestHits/02%20With%20a%20Little%20Help%20From%20My%20Friends.mp3"> 
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg"><br> 
</audio>
```

Tested on Firefox & Chromium

Comment: Works in Chromium but not Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio controls id="player" style="width: 80%;"> 
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg"><br> 
</audio>
```

OR in your stylesheet you can give a width to the "player" ID.

```
<style>
    #player { width: 80%;}
</style>
```

Comment: its the html audio tag 
<audio  controls id="player">
                <source src="<?php echo $row->audio_pfad; ?>" type="audio/mpeg"><br>

              </audio>

and i ant to style the size in % in CSS and not with px.

Comment: @AdrianGörisch updated answer. let me know if that works.